# Using ternary operator to conditionally set value of a field

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have an object, and I want to set one of the fields to the return of querying the database using the value of another field in the object.  The approach below returns `null`, as Im sure it's not right, but I can't figure out the best way to do this.

`shared_user_email` should be blank if `shared_user` is empty, but it should represent the return of a database query if `shared_user` is populated.

I know that javascript variables are hoisted to the top of the application at runtime, but I seem to be falling victim to order of operations here.

```
    var newList = {
        title: $(ev.target).find('[name=title]').val(),
        description: $(ev.target).find('[name=description]').val(),
        dateCreated: today.toDateString(),
        owner: Meteor.userId(),
        owner_email: Meteor.user().emails[0].address,
        shared_user: $(ev.target).find('[name=shared_user]').val(),
        shared_user_email: shared_user_email_field
    }

    var shared_user_email_field = (newList.shared_user != '') ? Meteor.users.find({_id: $(ev.target).find('[name=shared_user]')
        .val()}).fetch()[0].emails[0].address : '';
```

**EDIT**

here is the server side method that is invoked right after the object is created, which passes `newList` to the server:

```
    Meteor.call('addList', newList, function(err, list){
        console.log(shared_user_email_field);
        return list;
    });
```

Comment: Are you sure there's not an `asynchronous` call going on somewhere?

Comment: im not sure exactly what you mean

Comment: I've never used `Meteor` (by the way, you should tag your question with it), so I was just wondering if it's not making an `asynchronous` call somewhere.

Comment: Please add your resolution as an *answer* to your question and then (after the time limit expires) accept that answer; that way the system can identify your issue as resolved. Also, don't add '[solved]' (and similar) to the titles of your question, leave that to the system.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var newList = {
        title: $(ev.target).find('[name=title]').val(),
        description: $(ev.target).find('[name=description]').val(),
        dateCreated: today.toDateString(),
        owner: Meteor.userId(),
        owner_email: Meteor.user().emails[0].address,
        shared_user: $(ev.target).find('[name=shared_user]').val(),
        shared_user_email: ''
    }

    newList.shared_user_email = (newList.shared_user != '') ? Meteor.users.find({_id: $(ev.target).find('[name=shared_user]')
        .val()}).fetch()[0].emails[0].address : '';
```